# Adding DropDown list in jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to display table's data with jQuery DataTable and sometimes apply an extra data filtering, using the output of a dropdown select input.

The main code for fetching data (fetch.php) is:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include('function.php');
$query = '';
$output = array();
$query .= "SELECT * FROM Part_tb ";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE part_manufacturer LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
    $query .= 'OR part_id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY part_id ASC ';
}
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row["part_manufacturer"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["part_id"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["part_category"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["part_stock"];
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

while the DataTable is defined in index.php as follows:

```
    var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"actions/fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[0, 1],
                "orderable":false,
            },
        ],

    });
```

In index.php, i've created 3 dependent dropdown lists, which load data from other tables. Now, i want to take the id of 3rd dropdown list and update the data of Part_tb in fetch.php accordingly. Below, you can see that when 3rd dropdown change, i call a function load_parts():

```
  $(document).on('change', '#sub3_category_item', function(){
    load_parts();
  });

    function load_parts()
    {
    var action = 'fetch_data';
    var filter_part_id = $('#sub2_category_item').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"actions/fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{action:action, filter_part_id:filter_part_id},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#user_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that i can't filter the data of fetch.php according to the selected id of `#sub2_category_item`. Could you help me on that?

I've modified the index.php as follows:

```
      $(document).on('change', '#sub3_category_item', function(){
    var filter_part_id = $('#sub3_category_item').val();
    $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
    fill_datatable(filter_part_id);
    });


    fill_datatable();

    function fill_datatable(filter_part_id = '')
    {
    var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "searching" : false,
        "ajax":{
            url:"actions/fetch.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{filter_part_id:filter_part_id}
        }

    });
```

and fetch.php:

```
$query .= "SELECT * FROM Part_tb ";
if(isset($_POST['filter_part_id']) && $_POST['filter_part_id'] != '')
{
   $query .= "SELECT * FROM Part_tb WHERE part_id IN (SELECT pcfit_name from Part_car_fit_tb WHERE pcfit_id ='".$_POST["filter_part_id"]."') ";
}
```

but dataTable crashes, when #sub3_category_item is selected. Any idea, how to filter datatable with the value $_POST["filter_part_id"]?

Comment: I suggest that you get all data by ```TABLE JOIN`` in SQL query. And you can define the dropdown columns by  ```columnDefs```.

Comment: let me add answer

Comment: May i know if you have seen my problem?